# Magento 2: Transactional Email Preview Error

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

I'm trying to get some transactional email templates working however when I try to preview them, I get redirected to the 'Email Templates' page and get ' ***An error occurred. The email template can not be opened for preview.'***

[image]

==============

## Debugging

==============

I checked var/log/system.log and get the following whenever I try to preview the email template:

```
 main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

I also checked the XML files in vendor/magento/module-email and didn't see anything out of the usual.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this issue, unlocking the config fixed this for me. The config.php file had multiple settings that were locked so once I reverted this, the previews started to work again.

I'm not sure what specifically caused this however this is what fixed it for me!